# Different browser gets different result for jQuery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make a $.ajax call but get a different result on different server.

In my js file, I have the following code

```
function getData () {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type:'GET',
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: 'sample.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(result){
            alert("successful");
        },
         error: function (xhr, status) {
             alert("failed");
         }
    });

}
```

The js file is included in an HTML file where there is a button with its onclick method as getData().

My problem is, it will pop up a "failed" alert window if I open the html file in IE or Chrome, but a "successful" window if I open the html in Firefox.

---

Solved:
I had the problem when trying to run that function from a local html file instead of on a server. And running on server solves the problem.

Comment: are you doing this on the local file system, or on a local or remote server?

Comment: Are you using a raw HTML file? Or are you actually running a server?

Comment: and why `async: false`? isn't that the point of AJAX?

Comment: Sorry.. just to clarify, not running on a server but local html file.

Comment: @SuckerForMayhem I'm not sure if that's relevant to my case.

Comment: @ChrisZ but it's, ajax isn't allowed by default for file:// protocol. but it can be enabled by turning on some flags

Comment: @Endless I tried removing `async: flase` but didn't solve my problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a security measure in browsers which prevents access to the file system. Firefox just has a different security measure that allows file access. Use a webserver and you won't run into this issue.

Comment: Thanks. I think your answer is correct. I am now running on server and the issue is gone.